# Receiving e-mail using Indy on Windows Server 2008-2012

Tags: delphi, indy

This code works for me just fine on Windows 7 - Windows 10

```
IdPOP31.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  IdPop31.Autologin:=True;
  IdPop31.AuthType := patUserPass;
  IdPOP31.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  IdPOP31.Host := 'mail.*****com';
  IdPOP31.Port := 995;
  IdPOP31.Username := '*******';
  IdPOP31.Password := 'password';
  Try
    IdPOP31.Connect;
    ShowMessage('Connected!')
  Except
    Exit;
  End;
```

But when I try to run it on Server 2008 or 2012 it does nothing.
When Port 110 was available all worked fine, now, as I said it works only on Windows but not on Servers.
Please, give me any idea how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: "_it does nothing_" because you don't care about potential exceptions. Sure you just want to `Exit` there? Not even logging it?

Comment: "*it does nothing*" - are you suggesting that `Connect()` is frozen and never exits, doesn't raise an exception, does nothing at all? The only time I've ever seen that happen is when the `Port` and `UseTLS` settings are mismatched, causing `Connect()` to wait for a greeting that the server never sends, because the server is waiting for a SSL/TLS handshake that the client never sends. "*it works only on Windows but not on Servers*" - the OS shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Sorry, "it does nothing" was an unfortunate expression. We used to use port 110, then they changed the port to 995, and while I tried to make it work I added addition code to my previous one : UseTLS
 
Without it the program, when on the ‘IdPOP31.Connect;’ line ‘thought’ several seconds, then 
moved to Except section. I added the above code, tested it on windows 7 and 10 - all was fine.
On the servers 2008, 2012, however, when on the  IdPOP31.Connect; line, the program, without any ‘thinking’, but instantly jumped to Except section.

Comment: @Peter Have you talked to them about their server change? When they changed the port, did they also change their SSL/TLS requirements to match? POP3 port 110 typically requires `UseTLS` to be either `utNoTLSSupport` or `utUseExplicitTLS`, whereas POP3 port 995 typically requires `UseTLS` to be `utUseImplicitTLS`. What kind of `Exception` is being caught by your `except` block? The code shown is fine, so the problem is likely with the OpenSSL library itself, ie if the TLS handshake is failing, for some reason. Like AmigoJack said, don't just discard the exception, at least log its details.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thanks for your reply. I discarded the Except section because I expected in reply something like that - ‘We use it in 2012R2 Server and everything is OK’ or ‘In order this code to work on the server you should add so and so code.’ The except section (on servers) tells - ‘Could not load SSL library’.  But the question remains - why Windows 7 - 10 could, and Server 2088-2012 could not load SSL library? Maybe someone has some experience in receiving e-mails of those servers? What am I missing in my code?

Comment: What am I missing in my code? Or rather - What servers do and especially where to prevent SSL library from loading? (Server 2008 of course, not 2088 from the future)

Comment: @Peter Now we are finally getting somewhere useful (see what happens when you don't ignore errors?). That error means either 1) the 2 OpenSSL DLLs (`ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`) are missing, or you don't have access to them, or 2) they are the wrong version for your Indy version (`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` requires 1.0.2u or earlier). Did you deploy the 2 OpenSSL DLLs with your app? Are they in your app's installation folder, or somewhere else? Which  version are they? When the error happens, what does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function (in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit) return?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau you are my saver! Thank you very much! At last my problem is solved (thanks to you).  The course of my problem was the missing of two files (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll) on the servers. Now everything works like a swiss watch. Thanks again